# Configure Visual Studio to publish the WCF service app on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I have created a WCF application (the one with .svc file). When I build this project, only bunch of DLLs are created but to be able to host it in IIS, I have to use publish option (right click the project and publish). This generates DLLs, copies app.config and .svc file. This bunch now can be hosted in IIS.

I want Visual studio to publish whenever i build the project. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at adding a [Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552362.aspx) and couple it with a [web deployment project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx) then when you build the solution the output of the web deployment project should be the same as publish operation - this approach is also much easier to use in a continuous integration environment such as [cruise control.net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)

Answer (score -1):

how about: a post-build event, running **msbuild /target:Publish**.